# Web workers - How do they work?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I'm trying to understand [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers#section_11):

HTML (main code):

```
   <html>  
     <title>Test threads fibonacci</title>  
     <body>  

     <div id="result"></div>  

     <script language="javascript">  

       var worker = new Worker("fibonacci.js");  

       worker.onmessage = function(event) {  
         document.getElementById("result").textContent = event.data;  
         dump("Got: " + event.data + "\n");  
       };  

       worker.onerror = function(error) {  
         dump("Worker error: " + error.message + "\n");  
         throw error;  
       };  

       worker.postMessage("5");  

     </script>  
     </body>  
   </html>
```

Javascript (worker code):

```
   var results = [];  

   function resultReceiver(event) {  
     results.push(parseInt(event.data));  
     if (results.length == 2) {  
       postMessage(results[0] + results[1]);  
     }  
   }  

   function errorReceiver(event) {  
     throw event.data;  
   }  

   onmessage = function(event) {  
     var n = parseInt(event.data);  

     if (n == 0 || n == 1) {  
       postMessage(n);  
       return;  
     }  

     for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {  
       var worker = new Worker("fibonacci.js");  
       worker.onmessage = resultReceiver;  
       worker.onerror = errorReceiver;  
       worker.postMessage(n - i);  
     }  
  };
```

I have the following questions:

- When exactly the worker code starts to run ? Immediately after the execution of `var worker = new Worker("fibonacci.js");` ?
- Is that true that `onmessage = function(event) { ... }` assignment in the worker code will be executed before `worker.postMessage("5");` in the main code ?
- Can worker code access global variables that are defined in the main code (like `worker`)?
- Can main code access global variables that are defined in the worker code (like `results`)?
- It seems to me that `worker.onmessage = function(event) {...}` in the main code has the same meaning like `onmessage = function(event) {...}` in the worker code (which is `onmessage` event handler of the worker). Where am I wrong ? What is the difference between them ?
- What this code should actually do ? When I run it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_web_workers#section_12) it just prints "5". Is that what it is supposed to do, or I'm missing something ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you haven't already, give the spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/) a read through. It *should* cover most or all of that.

Comment: I have to say that a Fibonacci calculator is not high on the list of things I'd've picked to build an example of web workers around! :-) Not if I wanted to do something that would be a simple and clear example. This may be useful: http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/  BTW, I also get `5` when I run that example in Firefox; I suspect it may have been written to an early version of web workers and/or `postMessage` and that Firefox 3.6 (now) supports a later iteration. (This is very cutting edge stuff.)

Comment: I want to learn this stuff from examples, and I saw some examples before wrote this. I still have basic misunderstandings in how this works. I would be glad if anyone could answer to my questions. Reading the Spec is too painful for me right now.

Comment: TJ do you understand why it is that the Worker in the main page (the one in the first chunk of code above) gets the messages posted by the Fib workers?  I mean, what makes it different?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [HTML5 Rocks: The Basics of Web Workers](http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/workers/basics/) for general tutorial.

- Workers will start as soon as you call the `postMessage` method of the worker.
- the function bound to worker's `onmessage` in the main code will work when the worker calls `postMessage`.
- global variables are not shared between main and worker threads. The only way to pass data is through messaging via `postMessage`.
- as you suspected, the `onmessage` on both worker and main code has the same meaning. It is an event handler for when the thread receives a message event. You can even use `addEventListener` instead, catching `message` event:

Main Code:

```
function showResult(event) {  
   document.getElementById("result").textContent = event.data;  
   dump("Got: " + event.data + "\n");  
}
var worker = new Worker("fibonacci.js");
worker.addEventListener('message', showResult, false);
```

Worker code:

```
addEventListener('message', resultReceiver, false);
```

The fibonacci example you took is a recursive worker example. If not using workers, it would be something like this:

```
function fibonacci(n) {
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return n;
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}

var result = fibonacci(5);
dump("Got: " + result + "\n");
```

(oh no, I'm not going to do a stackless for you. You write it yourself!)

Answer (score 1):

I also want to add that you can **debug** web workers **only** in **Chromium** based browsers. You have to select *Sources* in developer panel and in right column expand bottom line *Workers* and then choose check box *pause on start*.