# How does stack in Javascript works for parallel function calls?

Tags: javascript

I have read some articles and learnt the basic of stack in Javascript, which it operates in LIFO principles. However, most of the tutorial I can find used nested function call as an example. How will the stack operates for a parallel function call like this?

```
function first () {
  console.log(1)
}

function second () {
  console.log('expensive computation here')
}

function third (v) {
  console.log(v)
}

function runCallback () {
  first()
  second()
  third()
}

runCallback()
```

If `second` conducts some very expensive computation, will it block `third` from running? Since these functions are independent(most like to have effect by mutation outside), can I make `second` non-blocking without using `Promise.all`?

Comment: `function`s execute in the order they are called regardless of how expensive the computation is. `Promise`s by themselves do not dictate execution order, although they will `resolve` in order from fastest to slowest, based on Asynchronicity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If second conducts some very expensive computation, will it block third from running?

Yes, if `second`'s computations are synchronous. Once a function is called, all synchronous code inside that function will run to completion before the function terminates. Only once the function terminates will control flow be yielded to the caller - which, in this case, will then call `third()`.

> can I make second non-blocking without using Promise.all?

One option is to delay `second`'s run until all subsequent synchronous functions are complete, by putting it on the microtask queue, eg:

```
Promise.resolve().then(second);
third();
```

Or with an instant `setTimeout` (macrotask):

```
setTimeout(second);
third();
```

True parallelism, where `second` runs at the *same time* as `third` would only be possible with special environment features like web workers or a child process in Node.

Answer (score 2):

Web worker is an alternative for doing jobs in parallel.

If you want to know more about it.
[Web workers - How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896480/web-workers-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 1):

> can I make second non-blocking without using Promise.all?

Of course, you should run the *less expensive code* as fast as possible.
So by somehow, you add the *expensive computation code* into another thread (web browser API or node api, for example).

Due to the code moved on `api`, whenever it's done, it'll move to the queue then is executed when the call stack is empty (after `third()` method)

```js
function first () {
  console.log(1)
}

function second () {
  console.log('expensive computation here')
}

function third (v) {
  console.log(v)
}

function runCallback () {
  first()
  setTimeout(second, 2000); //or using Promise static method like this: Promise.resolve().then(second);
  third("any value");
}

runCallback()
```

Thanks [@Philip Roberts](https://github.com/latentflip/loupe) with great tool to visualize JS runtime.

[Real time demo here](http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=ZnVuY3Rpb24gZmlyc3QgKCkgew0KICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygxKQ0KfQ0KDQpmdW5jdGlvbiBzZWNvbmQgKCkgew0KICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygnZXhwZW5zaXZlIGNvbXB1dGF0aW9uIGhlcmUnKQ0KfQ0KDQpmdW5jdGlvbiB0aGlyZCAodikgew0KICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZyh2KQ0KfQ0KDQpmdW5jdGlvbiBydW5DYWxsYmFjayAoKSB7DQogIGZpcnN0KCkNCiAgc2V0VGltZW91dChzZWNvbmQsIDIwMDApOyAvL29yIHVzaW5nIFByb21pc2Ugc3RhdGljIG1ldGhvZCBsaWtlIHRoaXM6IFByb21pc2UucmVzb2x2ZSgpLnRoZW4oc2Vjb25kKTsNCiAgdGhpcmQoImFueSB2YWx1ZSIpOw0KfQ0KDQpydW5DYWxsYmFjaygp!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the name of that website? It seems very useful to help me understand the stack.

Comment: Oh yeah, Here you are: http://latentflip.com/loupe/?code=ZnVuY3Rpb24gZmlyc3QgKCkgew0KICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygxKQ0KfQ0KDQpmdW5jdGlvbiBzZWNvbmQgKCkgew0KICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZygnZXhwZW5zaXZlIGNvbXB1dGF0aW9uIGhlcmUnKQ0KfQ0KDQpmdW5jdGlvbiB0aGlyZCAodikgew0KICBjb25zb2xlLmxvZyh2KQ0KfQ0KDQpmdW5jdGlvbiBydW5DYWxsYmFjayAoKSB7DQogIGZpcnN0KCkNCiAgc2V0VGltZW91dChzZWNvbmQsIDIwMDApOyAvL29yIHVzaW5nIFByb21pc2Ugc3RhdGljIG1ldGhvZCBsaWtlIHRoaXM6IFByb21pc2UucmVzb2x2ZSgpLnRoZW4oc2Vjb25kKTsNCiAgdGhpcmQoImFueSB2YWx1ZSIpOw0KfQ0KDQpydW5DYWxsYmFjaygp!!!PGJ1dHRvbj5DbGljayBtZSE8L2J1dHRvbj4%3D